# assigning a value to an image

Tags: image, dice, assign

So I am trying to create a real simple dice game...more like a dice roller game and I have encountered a problem for which I have yet to find an answer.  So obviously I have 6 images for the die faces(1-6), but what I am missing somewhere is how to basically assign values to these images when the "dice are rolled".  So that when I begin to implement some game logic I can compare what the numbers of the die faces would be.  Here is what I have so far, and as usual any assistance would be much appreciated.

```
public class CrapsGameActivity extends CrapsActivity {
    private final int rollAnimations = 50;
    private final int delayTime = 15;
    private Resources res;
    private final int[] diceImages = new int[]{R.drawable.die1, R.drawable.die2, 
            R.drawable.die3, R.drawable.die4, R.drawable.die5,R.drawable.die6};
    private Drawable dice[] = new Drawable[6];
    private final Random randomGen = new Random();

    private int diceSum;
    private int roll[] = new int[] {6,6};
    private ImageView die1;
    private TextView die1_Total;
    private int die1_number;
    private ImageView die2;
    private TextView die2_Total;
    private TextView diceTotal;
    private LinearLayout diceContainer;
    private Handler animationHandler;
    private long lastUpdate = -1;
    private float x, y, z;
    private float last_x, last_y, last_z;
    private boolean paused = false;
    private static final int UPDATE_DELAY = 50;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        paused = false;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);
        setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
        res = getResources();

        for (int i = 0; i<6; i++){
            dice[i] = res.getDrawable(diceImages[i]);
        }


        diceContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.diceContainer);
        diceContainer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    rollDice();
                    die1_Total.setText("" + roll[0]);
                    die2_Total.setText("" + roll[1]);
                    diceTotal.setText(""+ diceSum);
                }catch(Exception e) {}; 
            }//end of onClick
        });//end of onClick listener

        die1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.die1);
        die1_Total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV_die1);
        die2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.die2);
        die2_Total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV_die2);

        diceTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV_diceTotal);


        animationHandler = new Handler(){
            public void handleMessage(Message msg){
                die1.setImageDrawable(dice[roll[0]]);
                die2.setImageDrawable(dice[roll[1]]);
            }//end of handle message
        };//end of Handler
    }


    private void rollDice() {
        if(paused) return;
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                for(int i = 0; i < rollAnimations; i++){
                    doRoll();
                }//end of for statement
            }//end of run()
        }).start();//end of thread
    }//end of rollDice()


    private void doRoll(){//only does a single roll
        roll[0] = randomGen.nextInt(6);
        roll[1] = randomGen.nextInt(6);
        diceSum = roll[0] + roll[1] + 2;    


        synchronized(getLayoutInflater()){
            animationHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
        try{//delay for smooth animations
            Thread.sleep(delayTime);
        }catch(final InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }//end of doRoll()


    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        paused = false;
    }//end of onResume()


    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        paused = true;
    }//end of onPause()

}//end of activity
```

I may not be doing it properly but the code (below). When I use this to see the numbers on the emulator, they are random and dont correspond to the face values of the dice.  So like if I wanted to total the face values of the dice (just ran it again now) 0 is for 6 face, and 2 is for the 3 face, which should give me a total dice face of 9, but I am getting 2

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    rollDice();
                    die1_Total.setText("" + roll[0]);
                    die2_Total.setText("" + roll[1]);
                    diceTotal.setText(""+ diceSum);
                }catch(Exception e) {};
```

Comment: It's unrelated, but posting code with `extends CrapsActivity` might get you laughed at a little.

Comment: I thought hey if I am going to be staring at code for significant amounts of time I might as well get a laugh out of the "minor things" so to speak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
roll[0] = randomGen.nextInt(6);
roll[1] = randomGen.nextInt(6);
```

There are your values.  You don't want the image to contain the data (or at least, I wouldn't bother).  Instead, you render the images/animations based on these values, and can then work with those values directly later.

If you wanted to store the values with the images, you could always make an object (GameDie) and store the images and current value in there.

Comment: They are just obviously random, too "random" to correspond to any die faces, so how would I use those numbers in the first place if they are random?

Comment: @FROSTYSMOOTH A 0 corresponds to a roll of 1, a 1 to a roll of 2, etc. You store your images in the array in the same sequence {face1,face2,face3,...} and then they match. Unless you had a reason to set it up for a random value of 0 to correspond to the 6 face on the die? Obviously, if you want the actual integer value of the roll, you'd still need to add 1 to each die, but you already did that when you summed the two rolls.

Comment: Then I must have done something wrong else where because when looking at the emulator to test this I have the first die with a value of 1 and a die face of 3, and on the other die I have a value of 1 with a face of 2...so both dice have a value of 1 but different face values are showing.  They were loaded in sequence which is why I think I am thoroughly confused.

Comment: @FROSTYSMOOTH, sounds like that might be the issue.  If you don't know which image you're loading into each spot in the array, you're never going to be able to make it work.  So, sort out how you're grabbing your images and mapping them to the array, and you should be good to go from there.